# How to display all methods of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I want to know how to list all methods available for an object like for example:

```
 alert(show_all_methods(Math));
```

This should print:

```
abs, acos, asin, atan, atan2, ceil, cos, exp, floor, log, max, min, pow, random,round, sin, sqrt, tan, …
```

Answer (score 374, accepted):

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get all properties that belong to an object, whether enumerable or not.  For example:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math));
//-> ["E", "LN10", "LN2", "LOG2E", "LOG10E", "PI", ...etc ]
```

You can then use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to obtain only the methods:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).filter(function (p) {
    return typeof Math[p] === 'function';
}));
//-> ["random", "abs", "acos", "asin", "atan", "ceil", "cos", "exp", ...etc ]
```

---

In ES3 browsers (IE 8 and lower), the properties of built-in objects aren't enumerable.  Objects like `window` and `document` aren't built-in, they're defined by the browser and most likely enumerable by design.

From [ECMA-262 Edition 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> **Global Object**
>   There is a unique global
>   object (15.1), which is created before
>   control enters any execution context.
>   Initially the global object has the
>   following properties:
>
> • Built-in
>   objects such as Math, String, Date,
>   parseInt, etc. **These have attributes {
>   DontEnum }**.
>   • Additional host defined
>   properties. This may include a
>   property whose value is the global
>   object itself; for example, in the
>   HTML document object model the window
>   property of the global object is the
>   global object itself.
>
> As control
>   enters execution contexts, and as
>   ECMAScript code is executed,
>   additional properties may be added to
>   the global object and the initial
>   properties may be changed.

I should point out that this means those objects aren't enumerable properties of the Global object.  If you look through the rest of the specification document, you will see most of the built-in properties and methods of these objects have the `{ DontEnum }` attribute set on them.

---

Update: a fellow SO user, CMS, brought an [IE bug regarding `{ DontEnum }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug) to my attention.

> Instead of checking the DontEnum attribute, [Microsoft] JScript will skip over any property in any object where there is a same-named property in the object's prototype chain that has the attribute DontEnum.

In short, beware when naming your object properties.  If there is a built-in prototype property or method with the same name then IE will skip over it when using a `for...in` loop.

Comment: Andy E, thanks for pointing this out. Clearly i was not aware of this and I appreciate your effort for digging this out and mentioning it here. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Roland: No worries. Maybe it's a little sad, but I have the specification stored in my Documents folder, so not much digging required really!

Comment: Is there no way to get a list of all methods in newer JS implementations, then? Like Node.js and V8? How do we do reflection and introspect objects like we used to do, such as for mock object frameworks etc? I thought I'd just forgotten JS, but I guess things have changed over the years :)

Comment: @d11wtq, with ES5 implementations, you can invoke `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, which will return even non-enumerable properties and methods.

Comment: since all objects inherit from their prototype, wouldn't it be better to do something like  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype) ` ?

Comment: @lfender6445 yes, if you want to find methods available to all instances of a particular class.  In the example by the OP, the object was `Math`, which is unlike other built-ins that are constructors. It only has static methods and properties that aren't inherited from anything.

Comment: This: "return typeof Math[p] === 'function' " should be "return Math[p] instanceof Function"

Comment: @programmer: that's not true.  Functions from another realm/context, e.g. `objectFromAnotherWindow[p] instanceof Function`, will not be instances of `Function`.

Comment: @AndyE you are correct for the use case you pointed out.  You can just compare it to otherWindow.Function, but i guess typeof makes more sense. but this is why i don't like the string comparison: "typeof function(){} === 'funcsion'" will return  false without an error, where as "instanceof FUnction" will return an error immediately ..

Comment: Please remember, The following usage will return entirely different results 

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date)
vs 
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype)`

Answer (score 74):

It's not possible with ES3 as the properties have an internal `DontEnum` attribute which prevents us from enumerating these properties. ES5, on the other hand, provides property descriptors for controlling the enumeration capabilities of properties so user-defined and native properties can use the same interface and enjoy the same capabilities, which includes being able to see non-enumerable properties programmatically.

The `getOwnPropertyNames` function can be used to enumerate over all properties of the passed in object, including those that are non-enumerable. Then a simple `typeof` check can be employed to filter out non-functions. Unfortunately, Chrome is the only browser that it works on currently.

```
​function getAllMethods(object) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).filter(function(property) {
        return typeof object[property] == 'function';
    });
}

console.log(getAllMethods(Math));
```

logs `["cos", "pow", "log", "tan", "sqrt", "ceil", "asin", "abs", "max", "exp", "atan2", "random", "round", "floor", "acos", "atan", "min", "sin"]` in no particular order.

Comment: +1 for the ES5 stuff.  IE9 will supposedly fully support ES5 so this stuff is good to know.

Comment: @Andy - Microsoft is taking IE9 very seriously which makes me happy :)

Comment: console.log(function(a){return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a).filter(function(b){return"function"==typeof a[b]})}(Math));

Thank you!

Comment: getOwnPropertyNames is the ticket. It even works in Nashorn. They just changed the names of the methods of the Java object, and I was able to figure out the new names by running  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Java)

Answer (score 66):

```
var methods = [];
for (var m in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[m] == "function") {
        methods.push(m);
    }
}
alert(methods.join(","));
```

This way, you will get all methods that you can call on `obj`. This includes the methods that it "inherits" from its prototype (like `getMethods()` in java). If you only want to see those methods defined directly by `obj` you can check with `hasOwnProperty`:

```
var methods = [];
for (var m in obj) {        
    if (typeof obj[m] == "function" && obj.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
        methods.push(m);
    }
}
alert(methods.join(","));
```

Comment: yeah, I'm just noticing that too. When I use somethting like `document` or `window` i get more luck. Frankly it is a bit unexpected, I don't know why it doesn't work for Math etc.

Comment: @Roland: It's because `document` and `window` are objects with enumerable properties provided by the browser, they're not part of the scripting runtime.  Native objects are and obviously the properties aren't enumerable.

Comment: Any E, i don't agree it's obvious. I mean, it is apparent since we can't seem to enumerate them. But I don't see the logic as to why those built-ins should prevent enumeration of their properties. Just curious, is there some part of the standard that says these built-ins should not have enumerable properties?

Comment: @Roland: sorry, I meant that it's obvious they're not enumerable since they don't show up with a for-in.  See my answer below for a quote from the spec.

Comment: @Mic: Math is a built-in object whose properties aren't enumerable.

Comment: This will only work for properties which enumerable value is set to true.

Answer (score 34):

Most modern browser support `console.dir(obj)`, which will return all the properties of an object that it inherited through its constructor.  See Mozilla's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) for more info and current browser support.

```js
console.dir(Math)
=> MathConstructor
E: 2.718281828459045
LN2: 0.6931471805599453
...
tan: function tan() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 20):

The other answers here work for something like Math, which is a static object. But they don't work for an *instance* of an object, such as a date. I found the following to work:

```
function getMethods(o) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
    .filter(m => 'function' === typeof o[m])
}
//example: getMethods(new Date()):  [ 'getFullYear', 'setMonth', ... ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3xrsead0/

This *won't* work for something like the original question (Math), so pick your solution based on your needs. I'm posting this here because Google sent me to this question but I was wanting to know how to do this for instances of objects.

Answer (score 12):

**Approach that works nicely with ES6 classes and inheritance**

This is likely what most newbie ES6 users like me mean when they are looking for "how to list object methods".

This has been adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714550/895245

```
const isGetter = (x, name) => (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, name) || {}).get
const isFunction = (x, name) => typeof x[name] === "function";
const deepFunctions = x =>
  x && x !== Object.prototype &&
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x)
    .filter(name => isGetter(x, name) || isFunction(x, name))
    .concat(deepFunctions(Object.getPrototypeOf(x)) || []);
const distinctDeepFunctions = x => Array.from(new Set(deepFunctions(x)));
const getMethods = (obj) => distinctDeepFunctions(obj).filter(
    name => name !== "constructor" && !~name.indexOf("__"));
```

Example usage:

```
class BaseClass {
  override() { }
  baseMethod() { }
}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
  override() { }
  get myGetter() { }
  static myStatic() { }
}

const obj = new DerivedClass();
const methods = getMethods(obj)
console.log(methods.sort())
```

Output:

```
[ 'baseMethod', 'myGetter', 'override' ]
```

Note how it also includes methods of base classes as most users will want to see which methods they can call on the object.

This method also works fine with the `Math` object:

```
console.log(getMethods(Math))
```

output:

```
[
  'abs',    'acos',  'acosh',  'asin',
  'asinh',  'atan',  'atanh',  'atan2',
  'ceil',   'cbrt',  'expm1',  'clz32',
  'cos',    'cosh',  'exp',    'floor',
  'fround', 'hypot', 'imul',   'log',
  'log1p',  'log2',  'log10',  'max',
  'min',    'pow',   'random', 'round',
  'sign',   'sin',   'sinh',   'sqrt',
  'tan',    'tanh',  'trunc'
]
```

Tested on Node.js 14.17.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Out of interest, what's up with: !~name  ?

Comment: @user48956 I didn't know, but https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/ explained, it's binary negation and converts -1 to 0.

Comment: Yes -- but its a little unusual to use binary negation unless you're dealing with bit-manipulations of numbers (for all other cases, usually use boolean negation: !)

Comment: Or to put it another way, why not -1!==name.indexOf("__"), or  -1===name.indexOf("__")

Comment: @user48956 performance is for beginners, real pros only care about [code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This worked well for me! Here's the above, converted into TypeScript -- https://gist.github.com/matthew-dean/9267ab91b0c701cfb956f7f0c1549b55

Answer (score 3):

`Math` has static method where you can call directly like `Math.abs()` while `Date` has static method like `Date.now()` and also instance method where you need to create new instance first `var time = new Date()` to call `time.getHours()`.

```js
// The instance method of Date can be found on `Date.prototype` so you can just call:
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype);

// And for the static method
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date);

// But if the instance already created you need to
// pass its constructor
var time = new Date();
var staticKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(time.constructor);
var instanceKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(time.constructor.prototype);
```

**Of course you will need to filter** the obtained keys for the static method to get actual method names, because you can also get `length, name` that aren't a function on the list.

But how if we want to obtain all available method from class that extend another class?

Of course you will need to scan through the root of prototype like using `__proto__`. For saving your time you can use script below to get static method and deep method instance.

```js
// var keys = new Set();
function getStaticMethods(keys, clas){
    var keys2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clas);

    for(var i = 0; i < keys2.length; i++){
        if(clas[keys2[i]].constructor === Function)
            keys.add(keys2[i]);
    }
}

function getPrototypeMethods(keys, clas){
    if(clas.prototype === void 0)
        return;

    var keys2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clas.prototype);
    for (var i = keys2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(keys2[i] !== 'constructor')
            keys.add(keys2[i]);
    }

    var deep = Object.getPrototypeOf(clas);
    if(deep.prototype !== void 0)
        getPrototypeMethods(keys, deep);
}

// ====== Usage example ======
// To avoid duplicate on deeper prototype we use `Set`
var keys = new Set();
getStaticMethods(keys, Date);
getPrototypeMethods(keys, Date);

console.log(Array.from(keys));
```

If you want to obtain methods from created instance, don't forget to pass the `constructor` of it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't because `Math` and `Date` (off the top of my head, I'm sure there are others) are't normal objects.  To see this, create a simple test script:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        alert("Math: " + Math);
        alert("Math: " + Math.sqrt);
        alert("Date: " + Date);
        alert("Array: " + Array);
        alert("jQuery: " + jQuery);
        alert("Document: " + document);
        alert("Document: " + document.ready);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You see it presents as an object the same ways document does overall, but when you actually try and see in that object, you see that it's native code and something not exposed the same way for enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a simple historical reason why you can't enumerate 
over methods of built-in objects like Array for instance. Here's why:

Methods are properties of the prototype-object, say Object.prototype.
That means that all Object-instances will inherit those methods. That's
why you can use those methods on any object. Say .toString() for instance.

So IF methods were enumerable, and I would iterate over say {a:123}
with:   "for (key in {a:123}) {...}"  what would happen? How many times 
would that loop be executed?

It would be iterated once for the single key 'a' in our example. BUT ALSO
once for every *enumerable* property of Object.prototype. So if
methods were enumerable (by default), then any loop over any object would loop 
over all its inherited methods as well.

Comment: since primitives usually inherit from a protype, this is possible `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)` for example

Comment: what do you mean methods are properties of Object.prototype. ? Every property is properties of Object.prototype in case of Object

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the other answers, here's a recursive way of finding all methods:

```js
// Find all methods of an object, up to the root prototype
function findAllMethods(obj, methods = []) {
  if (!obj) {
    return [...new Set(methods)];
  }
  
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
  return findAllMethods(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), [
    ...methods,
    ...props.filter(prop => typeof obj[prop] === 'function'),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all methods including inherited ones:

```js
function getMethods(obj) {
  const methods = [];
  do {
    for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
      if (obj[prop] instanceof Function) methods.push(prop);
    }
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  } while (obj !== null)

  return methods;
}

console.log(getMethods(Math));
```