# Remove additional function from Rhino shell

Tags: rhino, rhino-security

I want to use Rhino as a sandbox to run user supplied scripts on a server. I want to do that from PHP, which doesn't have Java bindings any more, so I have to use the command line interface (Rhino shell).

Unfortunately the Rhino shell adds some intrinsic functions to the environment that ruin the sandbox character, like file access and `runCommand()` which allows runnning arbitrary commands on the system.

Is there a way to disable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can just overwrite them with null or delete them:

```
runCommand = null;
delete runCommand;
```

I can find out which global functions and objects there are by [getting all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object/2946616#2946616) of the Global, which is stored in `this`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
```