# How to check if a string is a JavaScript command with PHP

Tags: php, regex

i need a solution to check a string with `PHP` and determine if it is a `javascript` command.

i want to generate javascript scripts dynamically in runtime.
but a string could be an invalid javascript command.

for example in :

```
 $str = 'hello';
```

`hello` is a simple string and not a javascript command but in:

```
 $str = 'str.split()';
```

`str.split()` is javascript commnad.

i want to know if a string is really a javascript command

Comment: Can you define "javascript command"? Are you looking for script tags, or javascript keywords, or checking to see if something is valid javascript, or something else?

Comment: Just a tip: When asking a question on here, it is often useful to state *why* you are trying to do something.

Comment: If you're generating it dynamically, why can't you just test it using a browser error console, or is it being generated from user input?

Comment: @JamWaffles: Yes it's being generated by user

Comment: @Omid Ah right. A curious case; can you give an example of why/where this user generated JS is used?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try using [a JavaScript linter written in PHP](http://www.overflow.biz/blog/lang/en-us/2010/07/07/jslint-php-class/).

Sure the JavaScript will need to be valid but it could work.

Just check if the linter says it's okay and then you can consider it as JavaScript code.

Edit: Example taken and edited from the page I linked to.

```
$lint = new JSLEngine();

if ($lint->Lint($js))
{
    // This is valid JavaScript, now we can do stuff with it.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the general concept is a good idea though. If he is generating scripts from users input then this could be one massive XSS target. Just sounds a tad dangerous to me.

Comment: Good, but i don't want to use external application due to performance

Answer (score 0):

You could always create an array of every javascript function then use `in_array($variable, $array)` to check whether the specified variable is in that array, however this would mean writing every single javascript function manually.

The problem you will have is highlighted in the thread below:

[How to display all methods of an object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object)

I hope you get your problem resolved.

Just to extend on this - [How to display all methods of an object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object/2946616#2946616)

This post explains how ES5 will allow you to do this. However you will need to find a way of getting the javascript content into a php variable, eg `<?php $blah = get_file_contents("thejavascriptpage.php");?>` - thejavascriptpage.php containing the javascript, then explode the arrayed response.