# How to print all functions of JavaScript non-objects?

Tags: javascript

If I have `var foo = 'bar';`, how do I get all the functions callable on `foo`, such as `toUpperCase`? It's not an object, so [Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258232/96588) doesn't work:

```
$ node
> var foo = 'bar';
undefined
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo));
TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyNames called on non-object
    at Function.getOwnPropertyNames (native)
    at repl:1:20
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at repl.js:190:20
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:87:5)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
```

[katspaugh's simple, elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312446/96588):

```
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo.constructor.prototype));
[ 'constructor',
  'length',
  'toLowerCase',
  ... ]
undefined
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *is* an object. Though the properties you are looking for might not be its "own". Have you tried something like `Object.keys(foo)`?

Comment: @32bitkid - It's not an object, it's a primitive string value. It will sometimes be temporarily cast to an instance of `String` (if you call a method of `String.prototype` on it for example). l0b0 - Do you want this for a general case (any type) or just for strings?

Comment: @32bitkid - As far as I know, it's just a *string literal* until you use it as object [[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#String_literals)]. I guess this question is all about getting properties from `String`, which is exactly what the linked question talks about.

Comment: @James_Allardice right on, sometimes my brain goes a little loopy at 4am. Insomnia wins again

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it.  Although, if you enter "String.prototype" in Chrome's console.  You get all the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods you want are on the `String.prototype`, the prototype of all strings, ruler of Valindor.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames('baz'.constructor.prototype)
```

Comment: +1, I knew there was a way! This will work for all primitive values too.

Comment: Could be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object(whatever))` as well.

Comment: @SomeGuy, you mean `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object(whatever)))`.

Answer (score 1):

use can use the below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var foo = 'bar';
    var div = '';
    var ob = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo.constructor.prototype);
    for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) {
        div += ob[i] + "<br/>";
    }
    $(selector).html(div);
});
```

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code for essentially the same solution as @katspaugh. But it's valid, so +1.

Answer (score -2):

Use eclipse :)

Or just look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String