# Get list of functions attached to a dom element

Tags: javascript, flash, dom, youtube

I'm looking for a way to get all functions currently attached to a javascript object (a dom element). I'm familiar with [using `for (var m in obj)` and getting the non-enumerable ones with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object).

However on any video page on youtube.com `document.getElementById('movie_player')` has the function `getVideoBytesTotal`, which isn't listed by any method I have tried.

The object in question here is a flash embed. Can the function come from it?

I'm lost. Is there some kind of wrapper around some dom objects, which dynamically adds functions?

Even having a list through other means that entering javascript through the console would be great.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `getVideoBytesTotal` is API fn https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getVideoBytesTotal and it can be added to object in any time. It means it can be defined after your query to get all functions of this object...

Comment: Thanks. How would one hide a function during an enumeration of properties, then add them back?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how Google's Youtube API works but if you call your function to get methods/properties of given object at time t0 and Google adds methods after some action at time t1 (t1 > t0), you can not get these methods in enumeration.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are sure that function getVideoBytesTotal is attached to DOM elenent? i have looked briefly to Google's Youtube API and I think that it is member of YT.Player class. Can you send me sample code what you are trying to do?.