# Loop through JS object which has knockout observable properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascript-objects

I have the following JS object:

```
function AdvancedFilters() {
    var self = this;
    self.AdvancedColId = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedComapanyName = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedClientCountry = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedClientCity = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedDatabaseLocation = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedUserName = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedEmail = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedPhoneNo = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedAccessFrom = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedAccessTo = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedCreatedOn = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedCandidates = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedErrorsReported = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedActive = ko.observable();
    self.AdvancedRequestes = ko.observable();
}
```

I have to loop through all the properties present in the `AdvancedFilters` object and do something which applies to all the properties instead of accessing each property separately. I have to something like this:

```
for (var property in AdvancedFilters) {         
         // do something with property     
}
```

I tried the above syntax but it is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display all methods in a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: You have to work on the instance: `var obj = new AdvancedFilters(); for (var prop in obj) {}`

Comment: is for loop working on function? have you really tried out this?

Comment: @Akhlesh the loop is working but I am storing the JS object in a knockout observable array using the `new` keyword so I have to check if the loop works on an observable array. Right now busy with other things but I will surely check this and update here later....

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
function AdvancedFilters() {
    var self = this;
    self.AdvancedColId = ko.observable();
    //...
}

var obj = new AdvancedFilters();
for (var property in obj) {         
    alert(ko.isObservable(obj[property]) ? obj[property]() : property);
}
```

Comment: That's clearly what he meant. He surely doesn't want to iterate the attributes of a function (although this is technically possible: A function can have attributes, too).