# Get functions (methods) of a class

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have to dynamically fetch the properties and functions of a ES6 class. Is this even possible?

Using a for...in loop, I only get to loop through the properties of a class instance:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = "hi";
  }
  someFunc() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
}
var foo = new Foo();
for (var idx in foo) {
  console.log(idx);
}
```

Output:

```
bar
```

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo).concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo.__proto__))`

Comment: take a look at the function i posted, did you need inherited properties?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This function will get all functions. Inherited or not, enumerable or not. All functions are included.

```
function getAllFuncs(toCheck) {
    const props = [];
    let obj = toCheck;
    do {
        props.push(...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    
    return props.sort().filter((e, i, arr) => { 
       if (e!=arr[i+1] && typeof toCheck[e] == 'function') return true;
    });
}
```

**Do test**

`getAllFuncs([1,3]);`

*console output:*

```
["constructor", "toString", "toLocaleString", "join", "pop", "push", "concat", "reverse", "shift", "unshift", "slice", "splice", "sort", "filter", "forEach", "some", "every", "map", "indexOf", "lastIndexOf", "reduce", "reduceRight", "entries", "keys", "constructor", "toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "__defineGetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupSetter__"]
```

**Note**

It doesn't return functions defined via symbols;

Comment: You could probably stop at `Object.prototype` if we really only want to get `class` methods. Otherwise, nice :)

Comment: True, that would be useful in lots of conditions too.

Comment: You'll also need to `.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj))` since `getOwnPropertyNames` will only return `string` keys. That means your example won't pick up an iterator function for example.

Comment: Nice solution. If you want to remove builtin things like `__defineGetter__` you can do `while ((obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) && obj != Object.prototype)`

Comment: Nice, but `obj` inside the filter is `null`. If it wasn't the `while` will never exit, right :)

Comment: Yes, when obj becomes undefined while loop stops

Comment: Don't miss out the extra brackets in @antitoxic's suggestion... otherwise you start getting the prototype of `true`, which is apparently not null, so you go back to `true` again the next iteration...

Comment: How can this work? When the loop exits, `obj` is falsy, so your filter will always fail because of the `typeof obj[e] == 'function'` reference. You need to restore the original value of `obj` after the loop. Actual sample output: "TypeError: Cannot read property '__defineGetter__' of null"

Comment: I'm not sure what I understand, if obj has prop a which is a function then obj.a will be true.

Answer (score 94):

The members of a class are *not enumerable*. To get them, you have to use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

```
var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo));
// or
var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo.prototype);
```

Of course this won't get inherited methods. There is no method that can give you all of them. You'd have to traverse the prototype chain and get the properties for each prototype individually.

Comment: Don't forget `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` too!

Answer (score 47):

ES6 adds Reflection which makes the code to do this a bit cleaner.

```js
function getAllMethodNames(obj) {
  let methods = new Set();
  while (obj = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
    let keys = Reflect.ownKeys(obj)
    keys.forEach((k) => methods.add(k));
  }
  return methods;
}


/// a simple class hierarchy to test getAllMethodNames


// kind of like an abstract base class
class Shape {
  constructor() {}
  area() {
    throw new Error("can't define area for generic shape, use a subclass")
  }
}

// Square: a shape with a sideLength property, an area function and getSideLength function
class Square extends Shape {
  constructor(sideLength) {
    super();
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  area() {
    return this.sideLength * this.sideLength
  };
  getSideLength() {
    return this.sideLength
  };
}

// ColoredSquare: a square with a color
class ColoredSquare extends Square {
  constructor(sideLength, color) {
    super(sideLength);
    this.color = color;
  }
  getColor() {
    return this.color
  }
}


let temp = new ColoredSquare(2, "red");
let methods = getAllMethodNames(temp);
console.log([...methods]);
```

Comment: Ignore your linter about the assignment in while statement as it is needed

Comment: This solution returns all the internal methods that I doubt people want, how would you get just the declared methods?

Comment: it return the all keys not just the methods

Answer (score 20):

There were a few issues in @MuhammadUmer answer for me (symbols, index `i+1`, listing of `Object` methods, etc...) so taking inspiration from it, I came up with this

*(warning Typescript compiled to ES6)*

```
const getAllMethods = (obj) => {
    let props = []

    do {
        const l = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
            .concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(s => s.toString()))
            .sort()
            .filter((p, i, arr) =>
                typeof obj[p] === 'function' &&  //only the methods
                p !== 'constructor' &&           //not the constructor
                (i == 0 || p !== arr[i - 1]) &&  //not overriding in this prototype
                props.indexOf(p) === -1          //not overridden in a child
            )
        props = props.concat(l)
    }
    while (
        (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) &&   //walk-up the prototype chain
        Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)              //not the the Object prototype methods (hasOwnProperty, etc...)
    )

    return props
}
```

This function will list **all** methods of an instance of the class including those inherited, **but not** the constructor and those of the Object prototype.

### Test

The function returns

```
[ 'asyncMethod',
  'echo',
  'generatorMethod',
  'ping',
  'pong',
  'anotherEcho' ]
```

listing the methods of an instance of `TestClass` (typescript)

```
class Echo  {
    echo(data: string): string {
        return data
    }
    anotherEcho(data: string): string {
        return `Echo ${data}`
    }
}


class TestClass extends Echo {

    ping(data: string): string {
        if (data === 'ping') {
            return 'pong'
        }
        throw new Error('"ping" was expected !')
    }

    pong(data: string): string {
        if (data === 'pong') {
            return 'ping'
        }
        throw new Error('"pong" was expected !')
    }

    //overridden echo
    echo(data: string): string {
        return 'blah'
    }

    async asyncMethod(): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve: (value?: string) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => {
            resolve('blah')
        })
    }

    * generatorMethod(): IterableIterator<string> {
        yield 'blah'
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great snippet and it works. However, a small caveat: it might not work as expected if object has properties defined by `Object.defineProperty` or es5-style `get propertyName() { }`. The problem is here `typeof obj[p] === 'function'`. The thing is property `obj[p]` getter will actually **get called**, but with incorrect `this`. So if property getter uses `this` it will lead to unexpected results, e.g. crashes. Solution - here `typeof obj[p] === 'function'` instead of `obj` use the original one passed to this `getAllMethods` (store it in local variable).

Comment: @Wicharek can you give an example

Comment: @MuhammadUmer [here is the code](https://gist.github.com/wicharek/01abfd68b99e8206229b90dd0bc917cf) I have successfully used in one of my projects

Comment: These were close but still have issues with getters, namely everytime you are checking the getter you are actually calling it, which is a recipe for potential disaster, and was blowing up when I was trying to implement. Here is a version fixing that https://gist.github.com/jasonayre/5d9ebd64299bf69c8637a9e03e33a3fb

Comment: Nice function works great, it there the possibility to list ONLY public methods?

Comment: @Magico As far as I know, `you can't`. JavaScript does not have a built-in way to mark methods as public or private. The only way I know to mark down a class method (in a js file) as public or private is by jsDocs. The problem is that the JavaScript's interpreter does not keep any information about JSDoc comments. They are ignored by the interpreter and are only used for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

To make members of class enumerable you can use Symbol.iterator

I had to get all allowed methods of object (including inherited). So i created class "Enumerable" and all my base classes inherited from him.

```
class Enumerable {
  constructor() {

    // Add this for enumerate ES6 class-methods
    var obj = this;

    var getProps = function* (object) {
      if (object !== Object.prototype) {
        for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object)) {
          let method = object[name];
          // Supposedly you'd like to skip constructor and private methods (start with _ )
          if (method instanceof Function && name !== 'constructor' && name[0] !== '_')
            yield name;
        }
        yield* getProps(Object.getPrototypeOf(object));
      }
    }

    this[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
      yield* getProps(obj);
    }
    // --------------
  }
}
```