# Why are my class prototypes not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

To structure my JavaScript code I would like to use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), the syntactical sugar for prototype inheritance new to ES6. I am having trouble though: it seems my prototype methods are not working as expected, which makes me feel I  may have a fundamental misunderstanding of JavaScript classes, and/or how they work.

Take the following code, which declares a traditional constructor `Cat` and modifies its prototype, and an ES6 class `Dog` with a prototype method defined within it.

```
// Traditional Cat Constructor
// ===========================
function Cat(name) {
    this.name  = name;
    this.sound = "Meow.";
}

Cat.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log(this.sound || "I don't make a sound.");
};


// Dog via ES6 Class
// =================
class Dog {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sound = "Woof!";
    }

    speak() {
        console.log(this.sound);
    }
}

var cat = new Cat("Bella");
var dog = new Dog("Sparky");
```

---

In **NodeJS** (tested with 4.4.2 and 6.0.0-pre), when I try to get the prototype of an instance of `Dog`, I get an empty object, but I am still able to call the prototype method on the instance.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(cat);
// -> Cat { speak: [Function] }

Object.getPrototypeOf(dog);
// -> Dog {}

cat.speak();
// -> Meow.

dog.speak();
// -> Woof!
```

---

In **Google Chrome**, where I expect the result to be the same (since Node uses its engine), I instead get the expected result:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(cat);
// -> Object {}
// ->     constructor: function Cat(name)
// ->     speak: function()
// ->     __proto__: Object

Object.getPrototypeOf(dog);
// -> Object {}
// ->     constructor: function(name)
// ->     speak: function()
// ->     __proto__: Object
```

---

I was getting an error in Node that said the prototype methods I defined in a class were not functions of instances of their classes, which is the only reason I noticed this, but unfortunately now it seems I cannot reproduce that issue.

Regardless, the above does not seams right, is there any explanation for why this code is behaving in this way?

Comment: see also [Get functions (methods) of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31054910/1048572)

Comment: I can confirm it is still the same blank output of {} when calling .getPrototypeOf() on NodeJS 14.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why are my class prototypes not working?

Only because the output is not how you expected doesn't mean it is not working. Neither the Node REPL nor `console` are standardized. Implementations are completely free to output whatever they want.

The only way to really know whether something "works" or not is to use it. So try to call `dog.speak()`.

> Regardless, the above does not seams right, is there any explanation for why this code is behaving in this way?

Class methods are **non-enumerable** properties, hence they don't show up in the Node output. Simplified example:

```
> var foo = {};
undefined
> Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {value: 42, enumerable: false});
{}
> console.log(foo);
{}
undefined
> foo.bar
42
>
```

Regarding the Chrome output, it seems you expanded the object. Chrome always shows enumerable and non-enumerable properties.

```
> var foo = {};
  undefined
> Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {value: 42, enumerable: false});
  Object {bar: 42}
> console.dir(foo);
  Object
    bar: 42
    __proto__: Object
  undefined
```

It also seems that the Chrome also shows non-enumerable properties in the summery. However, even though Chrome and Node share the same engine, they probably don't share the same logic for `console` or output generation.