# How to list Callbacks in a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering if its possible to list callbacks in a class?

I already tried the answers listed here: [Get functions (methods) of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054910/get-functions-methods-of-a-class)

But they do not list callbacks.

```
export default class Foo {
    public myCallback: () => void;
    private readonly bar: any;

    constructor() {
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))​));   
        // [ 'bar', 'constructor', 'biz' ]
        // 'myCallback' is not listed.
     }

    public biz() {
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the desired result? Your object will have a reference to only one callback (which would be the myCallback property).. what do you mean by listing all of them?

Comment: I mean get the name of the callback. My desired result would be // [ 'bar', 'constructor', 'biz', 'myCallback' ]

Comment: so what you really want is all the names of the properties of that class

Comment: Yes, but I already tried answers that supposedly lists all properties, but they doesn't list callbacks. I was afraid my question would be immediately closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the way the javascript code is generated by the compiler.

Since the myCallback property is never set it optimizes the code and outputs nothing in javascript.

```js
 var Foo = (function() {
   function Foo() {
     // no my callback property is generated since it's never used
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))));

   }
   Foo.prototype.biz = function() {};
   return Foo;
 }());
```

However if at runtime you actually set that property it will be present. Like this.

```js
class Foo {
  public myCallback: () => void;
  private readonly bar: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  public logMethods() {
    var props = [];
    let obj = this;
    do {
      props = props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));

    props.forEach(method => console.log(method));
  }
}


let a = new Foo();
a.myCallback = () => console.log('abc');

a.logMethods();
```

You can see the working example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20myCallback%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20readonly%20bar%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20logMethods()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20props%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obj%20%3D%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20do%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20props%20%3D%20props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20while%20(obj%20%3D%20Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20props.forEach(%20method%20%3D%3E%20console.log(method))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0Aa.myCallback%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('abc')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.logMethods()%3B%0D%0A).

Comment: Even if it is used it does not show? In my real code, in the constructor I have `socket.on("myCallback", this.myCallback);` Edit: Will try your edit

Comment: it's not about it being used, but rather it being set. in your case this.myCallback would return undefined. Most likely the code would fail. :)

Comment: Hmm I suspect you are correct, since I set the callback after the constructor elsewhere in the code. I will take another look at what I am doing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: you can check the link. it has a running example.