# Cannot understand class to function mapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
class Parent {
    print() {
        console.log('hey i am parent');
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    print() {
        console.log('hey i am child');
    }
}

x = new Parent();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(x))
x.print();
```

Though the [[prototype]] of x is an empty object but still It can access the print() function which is defined in class Parent.

I cannot understand why `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` is an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

It's in there, just non-enumerable. Try this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(x));

// ["constructor", "print"]
```

```js
class Parent {
  print() {
    console.log('hey i am parent');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  print() {
    console.log('hey i am child');
  }
}

x = new Parent();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(x)));
x.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think it's empty? It does have `constructor` and `print` properties, they are however not enumerable and not displayed by default on the console. (And of course it does have a [[prototype]] link to `Object.prototype`, but how/whether that is displayed depends on your console as well).

To inspect them, have a look at [Get functions (methods) of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31054910/1048572).

Comment: be this the case 
`function Parent() {
}

Parent.prototype.print = () => {
console.log('printing');
}

x = new Parent()
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(x));
`
this prints an object with **print** as its property. I cannot seem to understand why is this not the case above