# Issue with reference of copied object

Tags: javascript

I need to copy an object and its methods.
Hence i stringify the object and then parse it and add the methods from the original object (but bound to this new copy).

```
// Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054910/get-functions-methods-of-a-class
function getAllMethods(obj) {
    let props = [];

    do {
        const l = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
        .concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(s => s.toString()))
        .sort()
        .filter((p, i, arr) =>
                typeof obj[p] === 'function' &&  //only the methods
                p !== 'constructor' &&           //not the constructor
                (i == 0 || p !== arr[i - 1]) &&  //not overriding in this prototype
                props.indexOf(p) === -1          //not overridden in a child
               )
        props = props.concat(l)
    }
    while (
        (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) &&   //walk-up the prototype chain
        Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)              //not the the Object prototype methods (hasOwnProperty, etc...)
    )

        return props;
}

function copyObject(obj) {
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

    // Copy all methods
    getAllMethods(obj)
        .filter(prop => typeof obj[prop] === 'function')
        .forEach(prop => copy[prop] = obj[prop].bind(copy));

    return copy;
}
```

And here some tests:

```
var foo = { bar:2, f: function() { this.bar = 5 } }
var bar = copyObject(foo);
var baz = copyObject(bar);

bar.f();
bar.bar; // 5

baz.f();
baz.bar; // 2 instead of 5..?!
baz.f.apply(baz); // not working either, baz.bar still 2
```

Why does a copy of a copy not work as i would expect?

---

EDIT: In `baz.f` the `this` reference is still bound to `bar` for some reason.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `Object.assign()`?

Comment: @Barmar What would be the benefits of using `Object.assign()` over regular assignment?

Comment: Regular assignment doesn't make a copy.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting! However, in my actual code i deep copy a complex object, so i guess `Object.assign` is not suited.

Comment: True, Object.assign doesn't do a deep copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can only `.bind()` the `this` value on a function once. The `this` value is basically set in stone the first time you use `bind()` and after that, you're just "painting another layer" on top of the already-bound function:

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var f1 = myFunc.bind({
  a: 5
});
var f2 = f1.bind({
  a: 6
});

f1();
f2();
```

Also keep in mind that you can't rebind `this` on arrow functions at all:

```js
var a = 2;

var myFunc = () => {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var f1 = myFunc.bind({
  a: 5
});
var f2 = f1.bind({
  a: 6
});

f1();
f2();
```

Comment: So the solution is to not call `.bind()` in `copyObject()`, right?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I guess if you're going to be arbitrary copying objects and their methods, you'd have to give up any reliance on `.bind()` and just trust that `this` will work correctly when the methods are copied between objects (which of course won't always be the case).

Comment: Well, thanks for this clarification! It all makes sense now :-)

Comment: There's no reason to assume that the functions in the original object were bound to that object. In fact, that's kind of a strange thing to do, since that context is normally passed automatically. You only bind a function if you need something else to be `this`.