# What is a good way to automatically bind JS class methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I get tired of writing code like this:

```js
class Something {

    constructor() {

        this.method = this.method.bind(this);
        this.anotherOne = this.anotherOne.bind(this);
        // ...
    }
}
```

It's time consuming and it's easy to forget to bind a method. I aware of the class fields proposal, but it's still Stage 3 and seems to come with [some issues](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).

My current solution (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31055009/931860)) looks like this:

```js
class Something {

    constructor() {

        // Get all defined class methods
        const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));

        // Bind all methods
        methods
            .filter(method => (method !== 'constructor'))
            .forEach((method) => { this[method] = this[method].bind(this); });
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way, or if this method has issues that I'm not aware of.

### Update: Why Do This?

The problem I have run into is that if I don't bind my class functions in the constructor, I have to remember to call them "properly" later. For example:

```js
const classInstance = new Something();

// This fails for a non-obvious reason
someAction()
    .then(classInstance.method);

// This works of course but looks like we created a useless function if you don't know better
someAction()
    .then(result => classInstance.method(result));
```

Comment: I'd extract the binding out into a separate function, rather than being in the constructor

Comment: One option, considering you only need to bind methods that are called in a different context (usually an event handler), is to use arrow functions to call these methods without changing the context.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ES5 instead of fat arrow syntax?

Comment: Why do you feel like you have to do this at all?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. CertainPerformance, what is the advantage of putting it in a separate function? Just a cleaner constructor? Randy, Michael, and meagar, the problem I have run into is that if I don't bind in the constructor, I have to remember to call class functions the "right" way later.

Comment: What about `this.self = this` approach?  That's not discussed here...

Comment: I'm not familiar with that approach @Ryan could you share a bit about it (possibly in an answer)?

Comment: @DominicP - Just referring to the old idiom discussed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this.   Seems like this approach is no longer necessary or recommended so, nevermind :).

Comment: Ok, yeah, I see what you mean. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 34):

Use [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function in ES6 (generally called as arrow function)

```
anotherOne = ()=> {
...
}
```

Call like this `onClick={this.anotherOne};` no need to bind in constuctor

From the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an
> ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing
> environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an
> immediately enclosing function.

Comment: I don't see how this bind methods of an object to its instance at all.  Doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: OP already mentioned this, and said that he doesn't like the issues that come with it. @jfriend00 ? This is class field syntax, it means that `this` inside the function will be bound to the instance without an extra `.bind`, right? Probably not what OP was looking for given that he explicitly mentioned it as a discarded possibility, though

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Well, the answer does not show enough context of the definition to know that's what they were doing.  Certainly wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: You seem to be missing to mention that this relies on  the *public class fields* feature.

Answer (score 23):

It seems a bit late to answer this question but there is no accepted answer so I will try my best for people come here after me.

### To automatically bind `this` for all methods, you can use "arrow" function:

```js
class Something {
  constructor() {
    // Don't need to bind `this`
  }

  doSomething = () => {
    console.log(this); // `this` will be pointed to the instance
  }
}

const s = new Something();
s.doSomething(); // => `this` is pointed to `s`
```

**Note**: just make sure the classes extending this class `Something` will not use `doSomething` method in its `constructor` (eg: `super.doSomething()`), otherwise you will get an error.

### To answer the updated question: if you don't manually bind `this` using `.call()` or `.apply()`, the value of `this` depends on the way that method is called

For example:

```js
class Something {
  constructor() {
    // didn't bind `this` here
  }

  doSomething() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const s = new Something();
const funcA = s.doSomething;
const object = {
  funcB: s.doSomething,
};

// these ways of calling `.doSomething()` result in different values of `this`:
funcA(); // => `this` is pointed to the global variable (`window` in browser environment)
window.funcA(); // => same as `funcA()`
s.doSomething(); // => `this` is pointed to `s`
object.funcB(); // =? `this` is pointed to `object`
```

Beside that, the implementation of `.then()` method would be similar like this:

```js
class Promise {
  // ...
  then(callback) {
    // code...
    callback(); // notice how the `callback` is called - not as a method of an object
    // code...
  }
}
```

With your code example, the way you pass the callback into `.then()` method will affect the value of `this` inside the callback:

```js
const classInstance = new Something();

// `this` inside `classInstance.method` is pointed to `this` inside the
// `.then` method, not the `classInstance`, as `classInstance.method()`
// will be called as `callback()`
someAction()
    .then(classInstance.method);

// `this` inside `classInstance.method` is pointed to `classInstance`,
// as the way the anonymous "arrow" function is called does not affect the way
// `classInstance.method` is called, so `this`'s value is controlled by the way
// you call it inside the callback (anonymous "arrow" function) of `.then()`
// method.
someAction()
    .then(result => classInstance.method(result));
```

Comment: Why is this not an accepted answer?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [auto-bind](https://github.com/sindresorhus/auto-bind) like this

From usage example:

```
const autoBind = require('auto-bind');

class Unicorn {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        autoBind(this);
    }

    message() {
        return `${this.name} is awesome!`;
    }
}

const unicorn = new Unicorn('Rainbow');

// Grab the method off the class instance
const message = unicorn.message;

// Still bound to the class instance
message();
//=> 'Rainbow is awesome!'

// Without `autoBind(this)`, the above would have resulted in
message();
//=> Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Where would JS be without sindresorhus? ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an ES6 arrow function:

```
method = () => {
    //Do stuff
}
```

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

Comment: I don't see how this bind methods of an object to its instance at all.  Doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: OP already mentioned this, and said that he doesn't like the issues that come with it.

Answer (score 4):

[Class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) can be used to create functions automatically bound to the current instance.

```js
class X {
  fn = () => console.log(this.constructor.name)
}
const x = new X;
x.fn(); // regular call
const fn = x.fn;
fn(); // this is preserved
const fn2 = x.fn.bind(null);
fn2(); // cannot rebind this
```