# How to access the correct `this` when using a method as callback

Tags: javascript

### Duplication Notes

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) does not talk about methods defined in classes.

### Problem

When I use classes to define object: when I use the object's method as callback the `this` pointer does not point the object itself anymore.

*Example*

```
class MyClass {
  bar = 'my bar';

  foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
}

function runCallback(func) {
  return func();
}

const myClass = new MyClass();


// Output: 'my bar' (as expected)
myClass.foo()

// Output: 'undefined' (unexpected)
runCallback(myClass.foo)
```

### Question

How can I make Javascript use the *correct* value of *this* (= the object the method belongs to).

### Javascript knowledge

The *Problem* happens, because [`this` in Javascript means something different than in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/6702598).

Comment: I feel like people could just get this from [How does `this` work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used) if they bother to scroll down just a little.

Comment: @caTS Accepted answer in that post is missing TL;DR. But I guess most people who come to SO are looking for a way to get around their problem and not to get in-depth understanding. For those few souls, that answer will do the trick

Comment: Duplicate notes: classes aren't really any special case, and answers in the duplicate do talk about the class case as well.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for the comment. Classes might be a special case (unless proven otherwise; AFAIK classes have their own implementation in JS, which indeed would make them a special case). `Duplication` notice is about questions, not about answers. If there are class related answers in the other question, it would make them off-topic over there (Maybe the question focus in the other question is too narrow and should be broadened?).

Comment: Let's put it this way: this is one of the most common questions in [tag:javascript], and that duplicate is the canonical duplicate, and so far the need to address classes in a separate question hasn't come up…

Answer (score 3):

- *This answer is a community Wiki.* Please add further ways of dealing with the problem as you find them.

## Solutions without salt grains

*None as of now*

Accept, that Javascript does not support classes in the common way.

## Solutions that come with a grain of salt

### Use arrow-functions on callback

```
runCallback((...params) => myClass.foo(...params))
```

### Use `bind` on methods when used as callback

```
runCallback(myClass.foo.bind(myClass))
```

Why does it work?
`this` for `foo` gets specifically set to `myClass`

Problems:

- Fragility: Might be easy to forget `bind`ing.
- Blackbox principle break: The correctness of method `foo` will depend on how it is called, not how it is defined (however, note that this was the case to begin with)
- Readability: Code gets longer

### Use `bind` on methods during creation

```
class MyClass {
  bar = 'my bar';

  constructor(){
    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
}
```

Reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503531/what-is-a-good-way-to-automatically-bind-js-class-methods](https://What%20is%20a%20good%20way%20to%20automatically%20bind%20JS%20class%20methods?)

Problems:

- Maintenance: You need bind methods inside the constructor
- Fragility: It's easy to forget binding on (new) methods
- Memory: Functions will turn to per-instance functions (i.e. each object has their own function object)

### use `auto-bind`

Available as [library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/auto-bind/blob/main/index.js), or implement it yourself (see below)

```
class MyClass {
  bar = 'my bar';
  
  constructor() {
    autoBind(this);
  }
    
  foo() {
    return String(this.bar);
  }
}
```

Problems:

- Memory: Functions will turn to per-instance functions (i.e. each object has their own function object)
- Fragility: Don't forget to call `autoBind`

Implemenation of `autoBind`:

```
/**
 *  Gets all non-builtin properties up the prototype chain.
 **/
const _getAllProperties = (object) => {
    const properties: any = [];

    do {
        for (const key of Reflect.ownKeys(object)) {
            properties.push({ obj: object, key: key });
        }
    } while ((object = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(object)) && object !== Object.prototype);

    return properties;
};

function autoBind(self) {
    const props = _getAllProperties(self.constructor.prototype);
    props.forEach((prop) => {
        if (prop.key === 'constructor') {
            return;
        }

        const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prop.obj, prop.key);
        if (descriptor && typeof descriptor.value === 'function') {
            self[prop.key] = self[prop.key].bind(self);
        }
    });
    return self;
}
```

### Use fields and Arrow functions

```
class MyClass3 implements MyInterface {
  bar = 'my bar';

  foo = () => {
    console.log(this.bar);
  };
}
```

Why does it work?
Arrow functions are automatically bound ([reference](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1))

Problems:

- [Problems with arrow functions in class fields](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)

  - Not Mockable
  - Inheritance won't work as expected
  - Memory: Functions will turn to per-instance functions (i.e. each object has their own function object)function implementation (as opposed to one implemenation for all objects).

Comment: An extended example of `.bind` approach: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv401j63/) with an addition of possibility of passing context from caller.

Comment: 1. This fails to discuss one important difference of binding the method in the class (#1, #3, #4) - this means there are as many methods in memory as there are instances. Auto-binding or otherwise using these techniques on each method can lead to memory bloat when creating many instances. It might not be an issue if there is, say, only one or just a few instances created but just making all methods bound should be used sparingly. 2. One very easy approach to solve the entire problem without changing the entire class is `runCallback(() => myClass.foo())`

Comment: @VLAZ (1) Are you talking about the `bind` approach here?  Regarding the field/arrow approach this is stated (2) Your neglecting parameters. But the option should be added.

Comment: For 2. I didn't. I just used the example you gave in the question. It didn't have parameters. I hoped I didn't have to expand because it seemed trivial that if you *do* have parameters, you can just pass them in: `runCallback((param1, param2) => myClass.foo(param1, param2))`. After all `arr.map((x) => myFn(x))` isn't fairly well established idiom, as well. I thought it's a waste of comment space to explain how parameters can be used in a callback. At best a brief reminder about `runCallback((...args) => myClass.foo(...args))` might be OK but again - comment space.

Comment: For 1. All of #1, #3, and #4 - `autoBind` would make all methods instance-bound, thus there would be one method per instance. Also `class Foo { bar = () => {} }` will make the method instance-bound. If the same technique is applied to *all* methods, even if not needed, then a class with, say, 10 methods which is instantiated 1000 times, will have 10000 methods floating around in memory.

Comment: For me, the obvious choice would also be an arrow function at the call site.

Comment: @VLAZ Added memory information and arrow function. Thank you!