# Why is this class method, with a string name, not enumerable?

Tags: javascript

My class has a method whose name is a string. But it seems not enumerable! Even `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` doesn't work. So, how do I get the method name/key?

```js
class MyClass {
    'hello/world'() {
        console.log("You just called 'hello/world'");
    }
}

const my = new MyClass();

// For in loop
let keys = [];

for (let key in my) {
   keys.push(key);
}

console.log('For in loop: ' + keys);

// Object.getOwnPropertyNames
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames: ' + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(my));

// Call the method
my['hello/world']();
```

Comment: The methods of the class are not added to the instance. `MyClass.prototype.hasOwnProperty("hello/world")` is true

Comment: Unrelated, but please make it a habit to use the semi-colon statement separators. You would not want to leave this task to the automatic semi-colon insertion algorithm, which has some pitfalls.

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054910/get-functions-methods-of-a-class/31055217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is not an *owned* property of the instance object `my`. It is an inherited property that is defined on the prototype, and so `getOwnPropertyNames` will not find it.

You can list it with this code:

```
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames: ' + 
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(my)));
```

Or:

```
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames: ' + 
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass.prototype));
```