# es6 methods inside and outside constructor - knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6

Given the following class in es6:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = () => console.log('Hello World');
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('Hello World')
  }
}
```

What is the difference between foo and bar? I can call both via this (this.foo, this.bar). However, if I use this syntax in knockoutJS, Knockout is not able to find bar().

```
class Test2 {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = () => this.foo(); // endless loop
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('Hello World')
  }
}
```

I don't know if this makes sense, but I'd like to have what you can see in `Test2`. Mainly, I would like to get the override-feature into my knockout application. If I extend from `Test1` and override `foo`, I won't be able to call `super.foo()`.

My goal is to enable class-inheritance while allowing to override functions that are specifically assigned to 'this' (e.g. attached/dispose).

**Edit:** As a workaround, I can handle this like:

```
class Test3 {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = () => _foo();
  }

  _foo() {
    console.log('Hello World')
  }
}
```

This will allow me to use foo in knockout and still being able to override it using _foo.

Comment: Calling `foo()` or `_foo()` without `this` will always be a reference error, not an infinite loop

Comment: sorry i meant to say 'this.foo()' - edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between foo and bar?

See [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)

> If I use this syntax in knockoutJS, Knockout is not able to find bar()

Looks like Knockout is not up to date with the language development. Methods that are defined on `class`es are non-enumerable. See [ES6 Iterate over class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30881632/1048572) for how to access them.

> My goal is to enable class-inheritance while allowing to override functions that are specifically assigned to 'this' (e.g. attached/dispose).

You can always do `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);`.