# Why is the class return empty prototype object first time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a code in below, as you see when console.log the prototype of the class first time, it return empty, but the object new from this class actually can response those method, then I add function in prototype and bring new object successful, how can explain it?

## codebase

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea()
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

console.log(Polygon.prototype)

polygon = new Polygon(222,122)
console.log(polygon.area)
console.log(polygon.calcArea())

Polygon.prototype.test = function(){ return "test"}
console.log(Polygon.prototype)
console.log(polygon.test())
```

## output

```
Polygon {}
27084
27084
Polygon { test: [Function] }
test
```

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? In Chrome's console, I see `Object {constructor: function, calcArea: function}` for the first log entry.

Comment: See [ES6 Iterate over class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30881632/1048572)

Comment: @apsillers, it looks like cause the console.log of different environments, thanks your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how can explain it?

Methods/properties created through the `class` syntax are **non-enumerable** and it seems that the environment you log the value in doesn't show non-enumerable properties. `console.log` is not standardized, so different outputs in different environments have to be expected.

Creating a property through *assignment* always creates an enumerable property.

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea()
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
Polygon.prototype.test = function(){ return "test"}

// Note the different values for `enumerable`
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Polygon.prototype, 'calcArea'));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Polygon.prototype, 'test'));
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the class has prototype but console log not show it, my advanced goal and question what I want is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186968/how-can-i-implement-ruby-extend-module-in-javascript-like-the-example, if you have interests, welcome to try to solve it