# Where are the methods stored in class declaration in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I want to know, in ***javascript*** when using the `class` keyword where are the ***prototype methods*** stored? For instance in the below code I have declared a `Person` class containing a method `getInfo`, When I try to do `Person.prototype` it outputs an empty object. But I've also read that classes are just syntactic sugar for constructor functions. But now I guess there's still some distinction between them, So can someone please explain what is it?

```js
class Person {

    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    getInfo() {
        console.log(`First Name: ${this.firstName} \nLast Name: ${this.lastName}`);
    }
}

console.log(Person.prototype);
```

As far as I know if the same had to done using a `Constructor function`, Then it would be done something like the below code snippet.

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  console.log(`First Name: ${this.firstName} \n ${this.lastName}`);
}

console.log(Person.prototype);
```

Comment: Instance methods are added on the `ClassName.prototype` object; in your case, `Person.prototype` object. Try logging `"getInfo" in Person.prototype`.

Comment: Class methods are non-enumerable, so the snippet console doesn't show them as it doesn't show enumerable properties (see your browser console instead)

Comment: If you change your `console.log()` to log `Person.prototype.getInfo` you'll see it.

Comment: Re: what @NickParsons said - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186274/why-is-the-class-return-empty-prototype-object-first-time-in-javascript

Comment: You can transpile it into ES5 code using something like Babel or TypeScript to see exactly what happens with your code. They are pretty good at maintaining the same functionality. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=ie%2011&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKG9f0w6EALogK7AkqIAUAZgJbIkByYAtvADTTinsuASix4C4kgAtGEAHRMWg-NAC80BQM7wA3GPH4pM2fzZbVfSKa67xAX1ziA5vBIBJNPRS0ROfQSJoqCDwxiiOtAAGAGLMpNBKAFzQACSYhnIaVvC20AA6aAAylvFaSanpxpZKthFCNgT29kA

Comment: The equivalent would be `Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "getInfo", {value: function() {....})` not `Person.prototype.getInfo = function() {}`. The latter makes it enumerable.

Comment: Thank you guys, Now it is completely clear to me!