# How do I know JavaScript return types automatically for non-primitives/user-defined types and promises?

Tags: javascript, types, automation, user-defined-data-types

I'm working with an SDK and I want to go through all the namespaces shown in its API documentation and verify that all the functions return the correct type of object or if the function returns a promise. However, there are way too many functions to try this manually.

I came across [ES6 Iterate over class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881632/es6-iterate-over-class-methods) and that might work for functions that don't require input variables but many of the functions in the API I want to try out require inputs as well. It seemed like maybe passing in the .js file process it externally using something like Python might be a good idea but I haven't been able to identify a solution yet.

Overall, I would like to be able to compare all the expected return types from the API documentation vs actual return types for the respective functions and put up the differences on an excel sheet for later use.

Comment: What type system you're using?

Comment: You cannot check function return type, as its dynamic language, you need typed language like TypeScript

Comment: Thanks for your response @MedetTleukabiluly. I'm new to this whole process so I'm not sure what type system is being used. Since it's not possible to check the function return type, I'm just going to write the unit tests as suggested in the answer below. Once againg, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The first approach you should try is to see if there is a documentation for the SDK/API where you can read and see what the expected return values are. Due to the fact that it is a JavaSvript api, you kind of need that, or need to read through the code yourself, to know what ALL possible return values are.
If the code itself is documented with JSDocs tags, you could check what they are defined to return, something that most IDE's have support to show you during your coding.

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, I.E., a function could basically return anything. So the best way to know what you should expect is to check for documentation!

Comment: Just re-read the question and saw that there was docs. I would initially just hope that they where correct, and if wrong, submit bug reports.

Comment: Hi Jite, thanks for your response. The SDK does have documentation and my task is to find inconsistencies in the expected types from the documentation and what the code actually returns. Do you know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: So, we could basically say that you are QA testing the SDK?
Are there any unit tests written? If so, I'd say that running the tests should give you enough, if not, write some for it! :)

Comment: I suppose that would be the best way to put it. I think I'll have to write the unit tests so I'll get to that. Thanks anyway :)