# File and FileReader objects have no methods

Tags: javascript

Using [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258232), I am trying to print all the methods of the `File` object:

```
alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(File).filter(function (p) {
    return typeof File[p] === 'function';
}));
```

But I get nothing, and the same goes for the `FileReader` object.

Are these objects not part of the JavaScript standard, or are they simply method-less?

I am testing on Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at static methods, callable via `File.*()`.
There aren't any.

You actually want methods on its prototype (callable on instances of `File` objects).  Look at the properties of `File.prototype`.