# Log all methods on array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration, javascript-objects

I'd like to introspect methods available to me on an array object

```
> console.log(Array.prototype)
[]
undefined
> console.log(Array.prototype.push)
[Function: push]
```

How can i see or log all properties / methods available on an objects prototype?

Comment: [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display all methods of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-of-an-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) which return an array of all property names (including non-enumerable properties):

```js
const PrintAll = obj => console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));

PrintAll(Array.prototype);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```