# getOwnPropertyNames does not fetch methods of Date instance

Tags: javascript

At [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-of-an-object) it is suggested that `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` should return all properties of an object including functions. But when I do the following;

```
let date1 = new Date();
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(date1);
```

this returns 0 results. But `date1` has methods like `date1.toISOString()`.

How can I fetch all those methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOwnPropertyNames` returns - as it sounds - **own** property names. `.toISOString` is not a method on the Date itself - it's a method on the prototype.

For the same reason, the below does not log `method`.

```js
class C {
  method() {}
}
const c = new C();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c));
```

Rather, they're properties on the *internal prototype* of the object - `Date.prototype`. So, call it on the prototype:

```js
const date1 = new Date();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` only returns the names of properties that the object owns and functions don't own any properties by default.

All of an object's methods are properties of its [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), not the constructor function itself.

To answer your question, you can simply use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` on the constructor function's prototype to get all of its methods. To access the object's prototype, use the `Object.getPrototypeOf()`:

```js
let date1 = new Date();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(date1)));
```

To further understand this, look at this example which creates a constructor function, a method, and a static method:

```js
function A() {
  console.log('constructor');
}

A.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log('method');
}

A.staticMethod = function() {
  console.log('staticMethod');
}

const obj = new A();
obj.method();
A.staticMethod();

const property_names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A);
console.log('Own property names: ', property_names);

const proto_property_names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
console.log('Prototype\'s own property names: ', proto_property_names);
```

Static methods are stored in the function itself, so it is logged as the own property of the constructor function itself, while the methods are the own properties of the object's prototype.

ES6 Classes are also syntactic sugar for functions, so this works for classes too:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor');
  }
  
  method() {
    console.log('method');
  }
  
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('staticMethod');
  }
}

const obj = new A();
obj.method();
A.staticMethod();

const property_names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A);
console.log('Own property names: ', property_names);

const proto_property_names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
console.log('Prototype\'s property names: ', proto_property_names);
```